How derived category behaves for pushout of schemes
If $X,Y,Z$ are schemes with two closed embeddings $Z \to X$, $Z \to Y$, then we have a pushout $X \sqcup_Z Y$ in the category of schemes. Consider the induced diagram of bounded derived category of coherent sheaves and direct image functors. Is it still a pushout diagram, say, in the $\infty$-category of small stable $\infty$-categories? We may limit ourselves to well-behaved schemes such as varieties over a field $k$.

I think for perfect complexes we get the pull-back category. For coherent sheaves things might be more complicated since the pull-back functors might not even be defined on the bounded category (because of unbounded Tor).

In the affine case, Gaitsgory-Rozenblyum Volume II shows something like this in Chapter 8, Theorem A.1.2. It is phrased in terms of a pullback square of categories of ind-coherent sheaves along the right adjoints; which can be translated into a pushout square along the left adjoints in $Pr^L$, and therefore also a pushout square at the small level. I don't know how much it generalizes beyond the affine case, though

This situation is also discussed in [Kuznetsov, A. Simultaneous categorical resolutions. Math. Z. 300 (2022), no. 4, 3551–3576], see Lemma 3.6.

@PiotrAchinger Thanks, but here I'm using direct image functors instead of inverse image functors. I have added this to the my post.
